# iOS Date Formatting without year, with correct localization

Tags: ios, swift, date, nsdateformatter, dateformatter

Do you know how I could have the following date string `Jun 28` on iOS?

- `Jun 28` in English
- `28 juin` in French
- etc

I want basically `short month, day, without year`. (in the localized order, so `day, month` in French for instance)

I tried the following:

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMM dd"
let dateStr = dateFormatter.string(from: Date())
print(dateStr) // --> Jun 28
```

It works in English but not in other languages.

For instance if you set
`dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "fr”)`
It should output `28 juin` but it returns `juin 28`.

I also tried to use:

```
let date = Date()
let customFormat = "MMM dd"
let frLocale = Locale(identifier: "fr_FR")
let frFormat = DateFormatter.dateFormat(fromTemplate: customFormat, options: 0, locale: frLocale)
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = frFormat
let dateStr = formatter.string(from: date)
print(dateStr) // -> 28 Jun
```

^__ the order is correct but the month is in English.

What is the closest is:

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.timeStyle = .none
dateFormatter.dateStyle = .medium
let dateStr = dateFormatter.string(from: Date())
print(dateStr) // --> Jun 28, 2020
```

^__ but I don't want the year.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this part of the documentation is the key (I mean if I was just to re-set the locale on the formatter without setting again the template, I would get what you describe in the first case):

`func setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate(String)`

> **Important**: You should call this method only after setting the locale of
> the receiver.

and sure enough, when you do this, you get correct formatting:

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US")
dateFormatter.setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate("MMM dd")
print(dateFormatter.string(from: Date())) // --> Jun 28

dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "fr_FR")
dateFormatter.setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate("MMM dd")
print(dateFormatter.string(from: Date())) // --> 28 juin
```

By the way, there is [a really good session about formatters in WWDC'20](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10160/)